# Many-to-many "by proxy" relathionship in django

Tags: django, join, models

My data model consists of three main entities:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class Source(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='iuser')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Destination(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='wuser')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

I am trying to create a queryset which is join all sources with destinations by user (many to many). In such a way I would have a table with all possible source/destination combinations for every user.
In SQL I would simple JOIN the three tables and select the appropriate information from each table.

My question is how to perform the query? How to access the query data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django queries are done on the model object, its well [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). The queries or querysets are lazy and when they execute they generally return a list of dict, each dict in the list contains the `field` followed by the `value` eg: `[{'user':'albert','country':'US and A :) ','description':'my description'},....]`.

All possible source,destination combinations for every user?

I think you will have to use a [reverse relation ship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to get this done eg:

```
my_joined_query = User.objects.values('user','source__country','source__description','destination__country')
```

notice that i'm using the smaller case name of the models `Source` and `Destination` which have `ForeignKey` relationship with `User` this will **join all the three tabels** go through the documentation its rich.

**Edit:**

To make an inner join you will have to tell the query, this can be simply achieved by using `__isnull=False` on the reverse model name:

```
my_innerjoined_query = User.objects.filter(source__isnull=False,destination__isnull=False)
```

This should do a inner join on all the tables.

Then you can select what you want to display by using `values` as earlier.

hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks! It does the trick. I totally overlooked _values_ function. However, _values_ generates left outer joins which add empty element to the result. Filtering those only makes the query even more complex. Is it possible to make Django do the same thing only with inner joins?

Comment: use `select_related()` it will make sure that foreignkeys are not `null`

Comment: On what object should I use `select_related()`?

Comment: try using `select_related` instead of `values` on the same query :)

Comment: It doesn't work in my case, for two reasons:
1. `select_related` only supports forward relations
2. It is bound to a single model and doesn't allow choosing fields from different tables like `values`.

So far I am using a simple raw SQL query with 3 inner joins

Comment: This one works. Although, when I use the `filter` query it generates inner joins, but  when I use `values` on top of that it transforms to left outer joins. The induced NULLs are then filtered out by the WHEN clause. Not very efficient.